# Can you fix this VB.net script

Tags: .net, vb.net

Its supposed to choose the smaller number. I just cant get it to work Thanks for the help I will get!

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim A, B As Integer
        System.Console.WriteLine("Type a Number")
        System.Console.ReadLine(A)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Type another Number")
        System.Console.ReadLine(B)
        If A>B  System.Console.WriteLine(B)
            ElseiF A<B  System.Console.WriteLine(A)
            Else : Console.WriteLine("They are equal silly")
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This is not a script ... and is this homework ?

Comment: See the documentation for `ReadLine()`

Comment: It is homework and you see I coded most of it I just don't get the error.

Comment: Homework questions where you are asking for the answer are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your probably have several errors, some because of not reading the documentation for readline (it doesn't work the way it would have to for the above to function correctly) and some because you are trying to make the lines too compact.  Let each if and else be on their own lines.

Comment: I wasn't asking for answer I was asking for help you guys just come on here and start hating. It's not like im asking you to code it for me I was asking whats wrong and Krimson showed me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim A, B As Integer


    Console.WriteLine("Type a Number")
    A = Console.ReadLine()


    Console.WriteLine("Type another Number")
    B = Console.ReadLine()


    If A > B Then
        Console.WriteLine(B)
    ElseIf A < B Then
        Console.WriteLine(A)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("They are equal silly")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dude Thank you :) I kept on getting errors when I tried that.

Comment: I would check if it's actually an integer that your doing a comparison on. As of this code, your comparison is whatever.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Variable `A` and `B` are of `Integer` type

Comment: But what if a is pressed, not an integer.

Comment: Add Option Strict On to the top of your code.  Console.ReadLine returns string, yet you are assigning it to an integer variable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, exactly I was trying to explain to him about that. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway its automatically casted to an int when your assigning a string to an int variable. And as per the question. OP only ask me to fix his code and that is what I've done. Yes I could have included sanity check and `int.parse()` to prevent exceptions but that's not what op asked.

Comment: Not with Option Strict On it won't.  If the user enters anything that is not an integer, that code will fail.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway ok fine, but again that is no reason to amend my code. OP asked to fix his code, that's what I've done. Simple. No reason for downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but relying on implicit conversions is not wise.  You should always use Option Strict On with VB.Net.